# Angular: filtering on selected option and user entered value

Tags: angularjs

I have a need to filter on a dataset.  My form will look something like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Age</option>
    <option>CustomerID</option>
    <option>ProductID</option>
<select>

<input type="text" name="select-option-value">
```

What I want to achieve is the user selects an option, say age for example. Then enter a value for age in the input box.  Only when an option and value has been entered in the input box will the filtering be performed on both of these form elements.

How would I do this?

Comment: Wht do u mean by...... "....then filter on the option selected and the value." Not very clear :-(

Comment: I agree - more detail please.

Comment: I've added some more detail which I hope is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-model` on the `<select>` list so as to store the type of the filter, and `ng-model` on the `<input>` so as to store the value of the filter. The value of the filter is stored in a `search` object indexed by the filter type. See below:

#### HTML

```
<select ng-model="filterType">
    <option value="age">Age</option>
    <option value="customerId">CustomerID</option>
    <option value="productId">ProductID</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="select-option-value" ng-model="search[filterType]">

<div ng-repeat="person in persons | filter: search">{{person.name}}</div>
```

#### Controller:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.search = {};
    $scope.persons = [...];
});
```

---

Here is a **[demo of how all that works](http://jsfiddle.net/yzo4js0e/1/)**. Just select a type filter, and enter a value.

Comment: Awesome thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Glad that I could help :)